# Heroku with React and nodemailer build failing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm

Im having issues getting my build on heroku to work. Heroku is saying the build succeeded but when I pull up the page I get the Application Error page.

Here is my package.JSON for the React

```
{
  "name": "cloudveilheli",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase": "^4.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "re-base": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

and for the node.js

```
{
  "name": "cloudveilheli",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase": "^4.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "re-base": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

In the logs, I am getting an error that react-scripts are failing in the Heroku build process. The node and the react are getting fired but it fails soon after that.

And here are the heroku logs

```
2018-06-13T12:56:17.879178+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
2018-06-13T12:56:17.910185+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! file sh
2018-06-13T12:56:17.910189+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-06-13T12:56:17.912160+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-06-13T12:56:17.913985+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-06-13T12:56:17.922554+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! cloudveilheli@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2018-06-13T12:56:17.927487+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-06-13T12:56:17.928818+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!
2018-06-13T12:56:17.932398+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! Failed at the cloudveilheli@0.1.0 start script.
2018-06-13T12:56:17.932401+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-06-13T12:56:17.967183+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
2018-06-13T12:56:17.968219+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2018-06-13T12:56:17.968222+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-06-13T12:56:17.968224+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-06-13T12_56_17_935Z-debug.log
2018-06-13T12:56:17.992492+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-06-13T12:56:17.992495+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! errno 1
2018-06-13T12:56:17.996672+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! bluebirdheliapp@1.0.0 client: `npm run start --prefix cloudveil_heli_app`
2018-06-13T12:56:17.999397+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-06-13T12:56:18.004427+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!
2018-06-13T12:56:18.004430+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! Failed at the bluebirdheliapp@1.0.0 client script.
2018-06-13T12:56:18.004432+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-06-13T12:56:18.021046+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2018-06-13T12:56:18.021050+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-06-13T12:56:18.021052+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-06-13T12_56_18_005Z-debug.log
2018-06-13T12:56:18.046560+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm run client exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

while you push your app to heroku

> first it runs **npm install**
>
> later it runs **npm start**

so we have to declare in package.json what to run after npm install is completed and what npm start need to do.

update you package.json with:

```
    {
      "name": "cloudveilheli",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "npm start build "
  },
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
```

where postinstall works after the npminstall is completed
and create a server.js file like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

at dist/index.html give where index.html created in react

as i dont know react

Comment: if you didn't understand don't hesitate to ping me

Comment: Thanks! Want to double check, need to build the server.js file and add it to the build folder?

Comment: and would that script fight the scripts below in the code?